# How to create SQL query that takes data from multiple rows based on conditions?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, querying

I have two tables:

Insurance_INFO table:

```
    Name   |Insurance_ID|Insurance_Effective|Insurance_Expiry   |Insurance_type
    John   |30          |20100502           |20120502           |Primary
    Reggy  |50          |20110904           |20160803           |Tertiary
    John   |54          |20120503           |20170403           |Primary
    Reggy  |30          |20120503           |20140101           |Secondary
    Reggy  |39          |20110904           |20160803           |Primary
```

Service Table:

```
    Name  | Date_of_Service |Other_info
    John  | 20110102        |Foo
    John  | 20110102        |Bar
    Reggy | 20150304        |Sth
    John  | 20130206        |Other
```

Now I have to return:

```
    Name  |Primary_Insurance | Secondary_Insurance | Tertiary_Insurance | Date_of_Service
    John  | 30               |null                 | null               |20110102
    John  | 54               |null                 | null               |20130206
    Reggy | 39               |null                 | 50                 |20150304
```

There should only be at most one date of service per person per day taken from the Service table. Also, the Primary, Secondary and Tertiary insurance from Insurance_INFO table are selected where Insurance_Effective < Date of Service < Insurance_Expiry for each date that a person is serviced.

How do I write this query in Oracle SQL?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @TMNT2014 That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @TMNT2014 why did you remove your comment? I was busy earlier and didn't get a chance to go through it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a pivot. Before Oracle 11g you could do this manually with `MAX` and `CASE`:

```
select s.name,
  max(case when ii.insurance_type = 'Primary' then ii.insurance_id end)
    as primary_insurance,
  max(case when ii.insurance_type = 'Secondary' then ii.insurance_id end)
    as secondary_insurance,
  max(case when ii.insurance_type = 'Tertiary' then ii.insurance_id end)
     as tertiary_insurance,
  s.date_of_service
from service s
left join insurance_info ii on ii.name = s.name
  and s.date_of_service between ii.insurance_effective and ii.insurance_expiry
group by s.name, s.date_of_service
order by s.name, s.date_of_service;

NAME       PRIMARY_INSURANCE SECONDARY_INSURANCE TERTIARY_INSURANCE DATE_OF_SERVICE
---------- ----------------- ------------------- ------------------ ---------------
John                      30                                        02-JAN-11       
John                      54                                        06-FEB-13       
Reggy                     39                                     50 04-MAR-15
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ab98/1).

This is building on a basic join between the two tables, which [generates five rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ab98/10). The three `CASE` statements add pseudo-columns, with [only the appropriate insurance IDs in the respective columns](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ab98/9). Finally the `MAX` aggregate collapses the split-out values down so there is only one row per name/service date.

---

From 11g you can use the [`PIVOT` functionality](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55304) that's built in and effectively does the same thing for you:

```
select *
from (
  select s.name,
    s.date_of_service,
    ii.insurance_type,
    ii.insurance_id
  from service s
  left join insurance_info ii on ii.name = s.name
    and s.date_of_service between ii.insurance_effective and ii.insurance_expiry
)
pivot (max(insurance_id) as insurance for (insurance_type)
  in ('Primary' as primary, 'Secondary' as secondary, 'Tertiary' as tertiary))
order by name, date_of_service;

NAME       DATE_OF_SERVICE PRIMARY_INSURANCE SECONDARY_INSURANCE TERTIARY_INSURANCE
---------- --------------- ----------------- ------------------- ------------------
John       02-JAN-11                      30                                        
John       06-FEB-13                      54                                        
Reggy      04-MAR-15                      39                                     50
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ab98/2).

---

I'm assuming (hoping) your dates field are actually `DATE` and not `VARCHAR2` values and you'll just format the result to `YYYYMMDD` if needed. It would still work if they are strings in that format as they are comparable, but you shouldn't store dates as strings.

Also assuming you want the date ranges to be inclusive, so used `BETWEEN` which is equivalent to `Insurance_Effective <= Date of Service <= Insurance_Expiry` rather than `Insurance_Effective < Date of Service < Insurance_Expiry`.

Comment: +1 For including SQL Fiddle. I didn't know 'bout this one! =P

Comment: I'm still on Oracle 10g :(

Comment: Could you explain the use of MAX in this case? My understanding of it is limited to returning the highest value in a column.

Comment: @user3808188 - it is doing that, but for the highest value of the pseudo-columns generated with `CASE`. I've added a bit of explanation; hopefully it will be clearer if you look at the extra SQL Fiddle links.

Comment: I'm not seeing the difference between using (CASE WHEN (any of possible options) then ID) and using just ID. To my understanding, either way it returns one value on which MAX function is operating. I can't see how we're getting fewer rows with perfectly matched columns in this case..even after seeing the SQL Fiddle

Comment: @user3808188 - they have the same number of rows, but different columns; [with just ID](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ab98/10) every row has a single ID. [With `case`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ab98/9) that ID is put into one of three dummy columns depending on its type. The `max` collapses those dummy columns; which takes it from 5 rows to 3 and hides the duplicate dates. if you just did `max` on the original single ID column you wouldn't get the split you want, and the single returned value would be wrong/meaningless. It's the split into dummy columns that is key here.

Comment: So CASE creates dummy columns and fills it with data that satisfies condition in the group(Based on grouped by clause), and then MAX returns the row with maximum value? I'm trying to understand how the dummy column created by CASE statement knows to restrict itself to a given person and service date, thus allowing MAX to find the right value.

Comment: No, the `case` is applied on the simple join; there is no `group by` in that intermediate query. It takes the simple query - which links the type/ID to the name/service date from the join condition - and moves the ID you already had into one of three new columns. No grouping there. *Then* those dummy columns are collapsed with `max`, and it's here that the `group by` keeps the restriction by name/service date.